# Rails form to edit JSON object as text

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json, forms, mongoid

I'd like to make a form that lets a user edit one field of a mongoid object as rendered JSON text.  There's a field in the model that my rails app should not understand, but I want to expose a generic editor.  So for this field, I'd like to render it as pretty JSON, and expose it in a big `<textarea>` and then parse the JSON back in after any edits.

I can think of a dozen ways to do this, but I'm wonder what would be most consistent with Rails philosophy and least divergent from normal scaffolding.  Should I render the object to JSON text in the controller?  Then I'd have to repeat that code in the `new` and `edit` methods, and the parsing code in the `update` and `create` methods, which seems a bit kludgy.  Is there a way to define a helper or custom form widget that goes in the `_form.html.erb` that is more reusable?  Or maybe one already written?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make your own attribute writer/reader, in the model:

```
  attr_accessible the_field_raw

  def the_field_raw
    self.the_field.to_s
  end

  def the_field_raw=(value)
    self.the_field = JSON(value)
  end
```

whitch should be compatible with form generators and no extra code in the controllers.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Serialize the values as JSON.

```
class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
   serialize :values, JSON

   validates :start, :end, :values, :presence => true
end
```

Answer (score 0):

migration:

```
class CreateMyModels < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :my_models do |t|
      t.jsonb :name, default: {}, null: false
      t.jsonb :description, default: {}, null: false
      t.integer :another_param
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

model and concern:

```
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  AVAILABLE_LOCALES = I18n.available_locales
  include JsonLocalize
  json_localize :name, :description    
end

module JsonLocalize
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    def self.json_localize(*attrs)
      self::AVAILABLE_LOCALES.each do |locale|
        attrs.each do |attr|
          define_method("#{attr}_#{locale}") do
            send(attr)[locale.to_s]
          end

          define_method("#{attr}_#{locale}=") do |value|
            send(attr)[locale.to_s] = value
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

then you can have in your form:

```
.row
  .col-md-6
    - MyModel::AVAILABLE_LOCALES.each do |loc|
      = f.input "name_#{loc}"
      = f.input "description_#{loc}"
```

controller params:

```
def resource_params
   params.require(:my_model).permit(
     [
       :another_param           
     ] | [:name, :description].map {|attr| MyModel::AVAILABLE_LOCALES.map { |loc| "#{attr}_#{loc}".to_sym } }.flatten
   )
 end
```