# json field in edit form with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a project with `ruby 2.5` and `rails 5.2`. It has a model called `Fruit`, which includes two fields: `name:string` and `options:json`. I want to use options to store some data like `color`, `size`, etc.

Now I have a form:

```
<%= form_with(model: fruit, local: true) do |form| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :name %>
    <%= form.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :options %>

    <%= form.fields :options do |field| %>
      <%= field.text_field :color %>
      <%= field.text_field :size %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

It will successfully save the data to database, including the color and size in `options`. However, it cannot display the existing data in options when I `edit` it.

It means when I edit the fruit, if I don't set the color and size again, the existing data will lost.

Does anyone know how to make it work properly?

---

The problem marked as duplicate is different. In that problem, they are asking if a json object can transfer to string or not.

My question is to display the value in the form by key.

Comment: show your controller and model

Comment: You may need to look -> [*Complex Rails Form*](https://www.sitepoint.com/complex-rails-forms-with-nested-attributes/)

Comment: In the edit, retrieve the data and convert as string. Add to_s to the options and it will work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails form to edit JSON object as text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14288650/rails-form-to-edit-json-object-as-text)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I have found the solution.

The form will show each value by sending a getter method to `object`. The `object` is stored in the form builder as `form.object`, and represent the model.

However, when created a sub-form by fields, the object is not included. It needs to be passed in:

```
<%= form.fields :options, model: form.object.options do |field| %>
```

In this way, the `field.object` will be assigned to `options` as `Hash` format.

However, it's not enough. The form tries to get the value by calling the method. But the hash attributes cannot accept method call. `options.color` won't return the value so the value isn't shown on the form yet.

One solution is transferring the model to `OpenStruct`. `OpenStruct` allows you to call the key as a method to get the value. So my solution to make the form works is:

```
<%= form.fields :options, model: OpenStruct.new(form.object.options) do |field| %>
```